# How to use fixtures in django?

Tags: django, fixtures

I've a very simple app and I've created a fixture. A folder named as fixtures and a file named as `initial_data.json`. Following is the code I've in my initial_data.json file:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.model_in_lower_case",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "title": "my Title",
      "description": "Description goes here..."
    }
  }
]
```

But when I run the syncdb command, it says zero fixtures found and the data is not being saved. What's missing?

Comment: Have you tried to load fixture by hand (loaddata) in order to isolate problem?

Comment: Yes, It shows same message... 0 fixtures found

Comment: Have you tried to, insteat to write by hand this fixture, insert data into models and then export fixture? Perhaps do you have some mistakes in file ...

Comment: Are you sure that the application is installed (in INSATALLED_APPS list)?

Comment: `model_in_lower_case` is this your model name?

Comment: i've given my model name in lower case i.e. if my model is Person, I've given person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using manage.py /dumpdata to export the fixture.

save the fixuture under your **app** fixtures directory not your project directory.

name it initial_data.json and it should work for you.

when the json file does not fit to your database or is invalid, manage.py will throw an exception. I am positive that currently you didnt put the json file in the right place.

Comment: I placed it inside my app under the directory fixtures

Comment: are you able to use your model ? for example , can you see it in the admin page ?

Comment: I did the same before but tried it all again your way, used dumpdata and it worked! thanks!